# Subset from a data.frame to form a list of smaller dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

I wonder how to split my toy `data` below such that I get a list of smaller dataf.rames each of which containing a unique pair of `group` in it?

My `desired_output` is shown below. Is such a subsetting possible in `R`?

*As this is a toy `data`, I highly appreciate a functional answer where the names of the columns or their numbers can be different than this toy `data`.*

```
m=
  "
    y   group time outcome
    7   a     1    A
    3   a     0    B
    6   a     1    B
    5   b     0    A
    9   b     1    A
    4   b     0    B"

data <- read.table(text = m, h=T)


desired_output <-
list(
  data.frame(y =   5   , group =   "b"     , time =   0   , outcome =       "A" ),
  data.frame(y = c(7,9), group = c("a","b"), time = c(1,1), outcome = c("A","A")),
  data.frame(y = c(3,4), group = c("a","b"), time = c(0,0), outcome = c("A","A")),
  data.frame(y =   6   , group =   "a"     , time =   1   , outcome =       "B"))

[[1]]
  y group time outcome
1 5     b    0       A

[[2]]
  y group time outcome
1 7     a    1       A
2 9     b    1       A

[[3]]
  y group time outcome
1 3     a    0       A
2 4     b    0       A

[[4]]
  y group time outcome
1 6     a    1       B
```

Comment: What do you mean with unique pair of group? Permutation or combination? To me, your list[2] and list[3] have the same group pairing, thus not clear where the difference is. Also list[1] and list[4] do not even have a "pair" of group ...?

Comment: @tjebo, if you look at my `desired_output`, you see that all possible `group` values are always contrasted e.g., `list[[2]]` and `list[[3]]` while other variables (in this toy `data`, `outcome` and `time`) are kept the same for them. When `group` values can't be contrasted (as in `list[[1]]` and `list[[4]]`), then the data is returned untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the question is asking to split the input into rows that have the same time and outcome we can use `split` as follows.  No packages are used.

```
split(data, data[3:4])
```

giving:

```
$`0.A`
  y group time outcome
4 5     b    0       A

$`1.A`
  y group time outcome
1 7     a    1       A
5 9     b    1       A

$`0.B`
  y group time outcome
2 3     a    0       B
6 4     b    0       B

$`1.B`
  y group time outcome
3 6     a    1       B
```